# Find element in an array that is of a particular type in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia

I would like to use a function (I'm sure there is one) in Julia which takes an Array (or similar type) and a type (e.g. nothing) as input, checks each element in the array to see whether the element is of that type and returns the indices of the elements in the Array which are of that type. For example :

```
    typeToFind = nothing
    A = [1,2,3,nothing,5]
    idx = find(x->x == typeToFind,A)
```

Similar to MATLAB basically. I found some suggestions to use `find`, but seems its deprecated - Julia complains when I try to use it. I presume there must be a function of this kind in Julia, though I could of course write some pretty quick code to do the above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find` was replaced by `findall`, so you should try:

```
julia> findall(x->typeof(x)==Nothing, A)

## which returns:
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
4

julia> findall(x->typeof(x)==Nothing, A)

## which returns:
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
1
2
3
5
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `findall(x->typeof(x)==Nothing, A)` solves the problem, but it might be better to use `x->isa(x, T)` for some type `T`. The reason for this is that `typeof(x)` will not work for abstract types, since `typeof(x)` always returns a concrete type.

Here's a usecase:

```
A = Any[1,UInt8(2),3.1,nothing,Int32(5)]

findall(x->isa(x, Int), A)
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1

findall(x->isa(x, UInt8), A)
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2

findall(x->isa(x, Integer), A)  # Integer is an abstract type
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 5

findall(x->typeof(x)==Integer, A)
0-element Array{Int64,1}   # <- Doesn't work!
```

It also appears to be faster:

```
julia> @btime findall(x->typeof(x)==Nothing, $A)
  356.794 ns (6 allocations: 272 bytes)
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 4

julia> @btime findall(x->isa(x, Nothing), $A)
  120.255 ns (6 allocations: 272 bytes)
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 4
```